# Python 3.8 (Hangman Game Input)

Tags: python

From the question I’m about to ask you will realize that I’m just a beginner. Anyways, so I’m assigning a input function to a variable `word`. I then def a function and in that function I say:

```py
if ' ' or '-' in word:
     print('Error cannot...')
```

My issue here is whenever I run this and enter a word for my input it always prints `Error cannot...` even when I don’t have spaces or `'-'` in my word. That’s all thanks if you decide to help me out.

Comment: perhaps an example code would be useful. put it in a code block

Comment: Not sure what editor you're using, but it's converting your quotes into "fancy quotes" (the kind that look different at the beginning and end). Avoid using word processors for editing code, because you'll find that programming languages can't understand those kinds of quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this: `if " " in word or "-" in word:`. The reason you got the outcome you did is because a non-empty string is "truthy," in other words, it is considered true. If you have true on one side of an or and false on the other, the or will still output true.

Answer (score 1):

The `or` operator must compare two boolean values. So when you do

```py
if ' ' or '-' in word:
```

Python will convert both sides of the `or` into boolean values (`True` or `False`).
The problem here is that the left side of the `or` is just `' '`, which in Python is considered 'truthy' (in an if statement it will evaluate to `True`). So what you're really doing here is

```py
if True or '-' in word:
```

which will always be `True`. (`True or anything` is always `True` no matter what `anything` is).

What you most likely intended was

```
if ' ' in word or '-' in word:
```

Answer (score 0):

you have wrong logic `or` return True if one or more statements are  True.
In you case you can solve it in different ways.

```
 if " " in word or '-' in word:
    print('Error cannot.....')
```

Either you can have a list of characters which can iterate through the word to check whether a word contains any of those characters. For example

```
 l = ['-',' ']
 for c in l : 
   if c in word:
     print('Error....')
     break
```